# Edit link on a shape in Adobe Flash Pro

Tags: flash

I have shape in flash and to it it's assigned wrong link. Does anybody have an idea how can I edit this link in the .fla file? I spent over an hour searching for this property with no result.

10x for your kind help.

Comment: Are you talking about library objects and being exported in ActionScript or something else?

Comment: I have no idea I wish I could answer to that. Nevermind I've finally succeed  by listing all of the layers one by one studying what action scripts are assigned to them in an "Actions" panel provided in "Timeline" tab by right click on Action layer.

Comment: Ah - I feel your pain. Is this AS2?  Glad you figured it out.